# Sub string replacement in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My need is to replace, format a string to make it match to the key.

-- Replace symbols  ( ) , with no space,
-- replace single space with underscore,
-- replace BAND with BD

e.g. x_input = Higher Education Worker Level 10, Band 2 (salaried)
x_output = HEW_HIGHER_EDUCATION_WORKER_LEVEL_10_BD_2_SALARIED

I have written the code with nested replace which gives the correct output pattern

```
select 'Higher Education Worker Level 10, Band 2 (salaried)' as class_0,
replace(replace(replace(upper('Higher Education Worker Level 10, Band 2 (salaried)'), '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ', '_') as class_1,
replace(class_1, ',', '') as class_2,
replace(class_2, 'Band', 'BD') as class_4
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, i was reading through the snowflake regex pattern matching help, but was not able to find a cleaner way and it too nested couple of iterations.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly not the type of solution you were looking for, but why not put the logic in a UDF and then call the UDF in your SQL? It would keep your SQL simpler and easier to read.

Comment: I agree with @NickW that a UDF is probably the most elegant option. There is no built in function to replace multiple patterns in a single go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the one character replacement and removal you can use `translate()`, which will shorten the multiple `replace()` by a lot.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate.html

Query with identical results from the question, but way less code:

```sql
select 'Higher Education Worker Level 10, Band 2 (salaried)' as class_0,
translate(upper(class_0), ' ()', '_') as class_1,
replace(class_1, ',', '') as class_2,
replace(class_2, 'Band', 'BD') as class_4;
```

In one step:

```sql
select replace(translate(upper(class_0), ' (),', '_'), 'Band', 'BD') class_4
from (
  select 'Higher Education Worker Level 10, Band 2 (salaried)' class_0
)
```